# time range check with bit array and bit mask

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, mask, bit

I have a Java collection of `<String username, ArrayList loginTimes>`. For example, one entry might look like `["smith", [2012-10-2 08:04:23, 2012-10-4 06:34:21]]`. The times have one second resolution. I am looking to output a list of usernames for all users that have logged in at least twice in a period that is more than 24 hrs apart but less than 7 days apart.

There is a simple O(n^2) way to do this where for a given user you compare each login time to every other login time and check to see if they match the required conditions. There are also a few O(nlogn) methods, such as storing the loginTimes as a binary search tree, and for each login time (N of them), look through the tree (log N) to see if there is another login time to match the requirements.

My understanding is that there is also a solution (O(n) or better?) where you create a bit array (BitSet) from the login times, and use some sort of a mask to check for the required conditions (at least two login times 24 hrs apart but less than 7 days apart). Anybody know how this could be achieved? Or other possible efficient (O(n) or better) solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in O(M * NlogN) where M is the no. of users (size of the collection) and N the average length of loginTimes (it's an array):

For every user in the collection do:

1- sort the list loginTimes. This is a O(NlogN) task

2- scan the list and search if your constraints apply. This can be done in O(N) time.

So, for every user the total cost is O(N) + O(NlogN) => O(2N*logN) => O(NlogN)